# What is the syntax code for usleep in Lua?

Tags: lua

I want to put some number of sleeps in my code but I don't know the correct syntax. I want to put it inside the `TouchMove` so that every move of the pixel will have a certain number of sleeps before moving to another pixel.

```
--this program will pick random spots for x,y and will slide down 5 pixels

--define section
local iX
local iY
local iLoop

--initialize variables
--randomize variables
iX=40
iY=math.random(100,150)


--touchdown finger
--execute move for touchup

print("TouchDown ".. "(" .. iX .. "," .. iY .. ")" )

--touchmove finger
--slide down 5 pixels

for iLoop = 1,5 do
  --compute for next pixel
  iX= iX - 1

  --execute move for touchmove
  print("TouchMove ".. "(" .. iX..","..iY .. ")" )
end



--pick up finger

--execute move for touchup

print("TouchUp " .. "(" .. iX .. "," .. iY .. ")" )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://lua-users.org/wiki/SleepFunction
http://linux.die.net/man/3/usleep

And  here an example:
http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/lua/lua_lua_calls_c.htm#_Make_an_msleep_Function

```
usleep(x)
```

Comment: np needed 30 sec googeling